# Column <name> is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql

I am fairly new to SQL and have a simple question regarding the error message I received (Title of this question).  I'm trying to find the total value of the items in inventory (itemQuantity * itemCost), the average item cost, and the potential lost revenue (itemQuantity * itemMktValue)

```
SELECT
    (itemQuantity * itemCost) 'Total',
    AVG (itemCost) 'AvgerageItemCost',
    (itemQuantity * itemMktValue) 'LossedRevenue'
FROM
    Item;
```

If anyone could help me out it would be much appreciated.

Comment: try `SELECT (itemQuantity * itemCost) as Total, AVG (itemCost) as AvgerageItemCost, (itemQuantity * itemMktValue) as LossedRevenue`
FROM Item;

Comment: What does the data that you're querying look like? We can help better with a data example.

Answer (score 3):

Your `select` statement contains an aggregation function in it (`AVG`).  Because of this, SQL assumes that you have an aggregation query.

There is no `group by` clause, so SQL is expecting everything to be aggregated, as in:

```
select sum(itemQuantity), count(*)
from item
```

However, in your query, you have several variables that are not the arguments to aggregation functions -- `itemQuantity` for example.  Presumably, you want something like:

```
SELECT sum(itemQuantity * itemCost) 'Total',
       AVG (itemCost) 'AvgerageItemCost',
       sum(itemQuantity * itemMktValue) 'LossedRevenue'
FROM Item;
```

You might also want this information on a per-item basis, in which case, you would use `group by`:

```
SELECT itemid, sum(itemQuantity * itemCost) 'Total',
       AVG (itemCost) 'AvgerageItemCost',
       sum(itemQuantity * itemMktValue) 'LossedRevenue'
FROM Item
group by itemid
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon! Very helpful!

Comment: @TessBrookes . . . I'm glad the explanation helps.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT
    SUM(itemQuantity * itemCost) 'Total',
    AVG (itemCost) 'AvgerageItemCost',
    SUM(itemQuantity * itemMktValue) 'LossedRevenue'
FROM
    Item;
```

Comment: So simple, thank you, Mark. I knew it would be something easy like that!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need something like this:

```
SELECT
    SUM((itemQuantity * itemCost) 'Total',
    AVG (itemCost) 'AvgerageItemCost',
    SUM(itemQuantity * itemMktValue) 'LossedRevenue'
FROM
    Item;
```